# How to achieve this kind of custom brush in Blender?

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

I am trying to create a brush that allows for seamless alpha textures that can be drawn curved. The result should be similar to what is found in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eY2_EPG-zWY).

This is what I am currently getting.

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi M, welcome to Blender.SE. I would downvote this, but seeing as your new, I'll give you some pointers. Please ***edit*** your question to include more information. Don't depend on the link(!), the question has to be valid, without the link. Add screenshots and a text description of the brush. Also, show your research effort. Stackexchange isn't a volunteer work site, but a question-answer site. Also remove any extraneous text ('tnx for your time!') which doesn't help the question. Please read the articles on [asking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: See https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the suggestion in the previous answers, I made the brush to work closing to the ZBrush.

I used a SculpDraw with a custom Texture and Rake activated.

Stroke Method to Space and set the space to 30%, in this case.

I tested in a double subdivided cube and I used a Multiresolution modifier with a value of 6.

Unfortunately, it does not work well on too close curves, but I think it's a good start.

Also, I'm providing a screenshot of my Blender setup.

Just in case, I'm using the 2.79b version.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This isn't currently possible in blender in the way that the video showing the curving stroke works in ZBrush - closest you can get is to set a texture brush as View Plane and set it to Rake, and fiddle with the stroke spacing - but it will not adaptively twist the projection of the brush texture as ZBrush does with the custom brush you show there. Blender does have the 'lazy mouse' setting in the stroke with Shift S, but that still doesn't solve the problem with the desired twist of the image as it is projected. Could be a very good proposal on the community pages on rightclickselect.com.

Comment: Can you propose that?
I am not valid for that

Answer (score 0):

use a texture on the draw brush in sculpting
use sculpt mode and then open the drop-down textures in the properties panel on the workspace settings click new texture and then in the properties panel in the textures tab import a image or texture[image: workspace settings]

[image: textures]

Comment: tnQ for your time but I am looking for that specific brush which make it possible to use a seamless alpha textures in a curved way.